# Visual Studio Community 2015 and reports?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

What should i install to have reports control, to design reports in microsoft visual studio community 2015?
(free reports from Mirosoft)
Cause when i installed pure vc# from vc_community.exe installer there is no reports section and no reports designer control.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, had to install sql data tools, now works.